# Use Helm variables in entrypoint script

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm struggling to use Helm variables within my entry script for my container, when deploying to AKS. Running locally work perfectly fine, as I'm specifying them as docker -e argument. How do I pass arguments, either specified as helm variables and/or overwritten when issuing the helm install command?

Entry script start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

GH_OWNER=$GH_OWNER
GH_REPOSITORY=$GH_REPOSITORY
GH_TOKEN=$GH_TOKEN

echo "variables"
echo $GH_TOKEN
echo $GH_OWNER
echo $GH_REPOSITORY
echo ${GH_TOKEN}
echo ${GH_OWNER}
echo ${GH_REPOSITORY}
env
```

Docker file

```
# base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

#input GitHub runner version argument
ARG RUNNER_VERSION
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# update the base packages + add a non-sudo user
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && useradd -m docker

# install the packages and dependencies along with jq so we can parse JSON (add additional packages as necessary)
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl nodejs wget unzip vim git azure-cli jq build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3 python3-venv python3-dev python3-pip

# cd into the user directory, download and unzip the github actions runner
RUN cd /home/docker && mkdir actions-runner && cd actions-runner \
    && curl -O -L https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v${RUNNER_VERSION}/actions-runner-linux-x64-${RUNNER_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar xzf ./actions-runner-linux-x64-${RUNNER_VERSION}.tar.gz

# install some additional dependencies
RUN chown -R docker ~docker && /home/docker/actions-runner/bin/installdependencies.sh

# add over the start.sh script
ADD scripts/start.sh start.sh

# make the script executable
RUN chmod +x start.sh

# set the user to "docker" so all subsequent commands are run as the docker user
USER docker

# set the entrypoint to the start.sh script
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

Helm values

```
replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: somecreg.azurecr.io/ghrunner
  pullPolicy: Always
  # tag: latest  

imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

env:
  GH_TOKEN: "SET"
  GH_OWNER: "SET"
  GH_REPOSITORY: "SET"
   
serviceAccount:
  create: true
  annotations: {}
  name: ""

podAnnotations: {}

podSecurityContext: {}


securityContext: {}

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 80

ingress:
  enabled: false
  className: ""
  annotations: {}
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls: []


resources: {}

autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80

nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []
affinity: {}
```

Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "hostedrunner.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "hostedrunner.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "hostedrunner.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "hostedrunner.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "hostedrunner.serviceAccountName" . }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          # livenessProbe:
          #   httpGet:
          #     path: /
          #     port: http
          # readinessProbe:
          #   httpGet:
          #     path: /
          #     port: http
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

Console output for helm install
[image]

Helm command (tried both with set and set-string and values to get substituted correctly)

```
helm install --set-string env.GH_TOKEN="$env:pat" --set-string env.GH_OWNER="SomeOwner" --set-string env.GH_REPOSITORY="aks-hostedrunner" $deploymentName .helm/ --debug
```

I thought the helm variables might be passed as environment variables, but that's not the case. Any input is greatly appreciated

Comment: you right about the last line :) helm variables not get passed as an env variable so shell script directly cant access it. i didn't get it exactly what you are looking for adding helm var to used by shell script ? also you have not shared template so can't get clear idea, if you are trying to access Env in docker passed from helm it's possible.

Comment: Yeah either Helm variables or other means of parsing parameters to your shell script at deployment.

Comment: can you share template file of helm how Env getting injected to deployment ? if it's env getting injected to deployment so when you docker run shell script inside will be able to access the env vars passed from helm template.

Comment: I've added the deployment.yaml file, is that what you are asking for? It's pretty standard.

Comment: did you noticed in deployment.yaml your helm variable are not getting injected ? so when your shell script run in docker or container it wont be able to access the Env variables.

Comment: When I run helm install, I can see the variables as 'computed values'.  If I look at the output for deployment.yaml, I do not see them injected (Adding screen shot of the console output). Do I need to add somthing to deployment.yaml  in order for them to be parsed?

Comment: yes that's the issues, update same into the answer please give it try once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add and update your deployment template with

```
env:
    {{- range $key, $val := .Values.env }}
    - name: {{ $key }}
      value: {{ $val }}
    {{- end }}
```

so it will add the env block into your deployment section and your **shell** script when will run inside the docker, it will be able to access the Environment variables

Deployment **env** example

```
containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: <Your Docker image>
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

Ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container

If you will implement above one those variables will get set as Environment variables and Docker will be able to access it(shell script inside the container).

You can also use the configmap and secret of Kubernetes to set values at **Env** level.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I expect that configmap/secret approach is a more common way of setting env vars in the container?

Comment: yes, you are right. if it's something important you can keep it in secret else configmap and inject it to deployment. it would be easy to manage also single configmap storing multiple vars instead managing different and creating long deployment YAML.